# FuelPHP SimpleAuth Login not Working in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, authentication, fuelphp

I'm having an apparently IE-only problem with FuelPHP's SimpleAuth login. It works fine on localhost, but on the staging version of the site I'm working on, `Auth::check()` always fails after login.

If I dump the contents of `Auth::check()` on validation of the login form, I get `true`, suggesting that the user has been successfully logged in. However, after I redirect the user to the next page (using `Response::redirect`), `Auth::check()` evaluates as `false` again. I don't think the problem is directly related to the redirect because even if I don't redirect the user, the login still fails.

For some reason this problem only seems to occur in IE (both 8 and 9). In Opera, Firefox, etc, the user login and logout works fine. As I said before, it also works in IE on my local development version. I can only think that it must be some cookie or session-handling problem, but I'm at a loss to figure out what the problem is. I'd be very grateful if anyone can shed any light on this!

I'm using FuelPHP version 1.1

Comment: When the user has successfully logged in, I believe a Session variable gets set.  Enable the profiler and have a look in both IE and FF to see what is going on.

Comment: Ok. Excuse the delay: the profiler didn't seem to want to work in IE8. In IE9 though: no session variables. In FF and Opera, 2 session variables loaded (username and login_hash).

Comment: Check to see if Cookies are enabled in IE.

Comment: I think Cookies must be enabled, because as I said, there's no problem logging in on my local version of the site. Also, I can dump the contents of the PHP $_COOKIE global variable, and it's not empty.

Comment: Update: I've found the login *is* working when used from other people's computers (not on my network). But I have two computers here that can't log in. I guess this suggests it's some kind of network problem, but I'm totally stumped as to what it could be or why it would only be affecting IE.

Comment: @NickF FuelPHP has a login_hash and based on your auth configuration it could be taking into consideration the different ip's. Look into the SimpleAuth config and also post your config here to for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I have been stacking on the same problem all day long, finally, I solved it.

In my case, the problem was on Safari / Mac, the session was killed every time after I logged in. In fact, it was because I use ajax calls( with relative path on the server ) to login my user, and apparently the ajax call send an user agent different with http calls, and the mismatching cause Fuel to kill the session.

The solution that I use is to disable the `match_ua` value in the session configuration.
For making things more secured, I enabled `match_ip` instead. I don't know if it was the good solution.

I still don't know why the user agent will be different. If someone can make me more clear on this problem, thanks a lot.